# Dotfuscator and VS2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, dotfuscator

All, we have just decided to bite the bullet and upgrade from `VS2010` to `VS2012`. The first thing I did as the lead for the upgrade procedure was to load an existing VS2010 project into `VS2012`. This worked fine for the WinForms project, but the [`PreEmptive`] `Dotfuscator` project was not recognised. I have Dotfuscator installed, and have regesetered for the 'Community Editon'. I have attempted to upgrade the existing install and uninstall/reinstall but nothing...

How do I incorporate a `Dotfuscator` project into my VS2012 solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All, after two hours of faffing about. Here is the solution...

You may already have Dotfuscator 4.9 (build 4.9.8500_2.0) installed, but VS2012 will not recognise this installation (the relevent VS2012 addin will not be 'linked' with VS2012). I first tryed a complete uninstall of `Dotfuscator` and reinstalled, suprisingly this did not work on a Sony VAIO running Windows 8, but did on a Windows 7 machine - this may have been an anomoly. To get the Dotfuscator project type in VS2012 on the Windows 8 system, I did not uninstall Dotfuscator, but merely reran the install package - this seemed to work.

I hope this saves someone else a couple of hours.